# Go to last file in vim

Tags: multiple-files

Many text files can be opened at once using

```
vim *txt
```

I know I can use `:<int>n` to move forward `<int>` files, but I don't know how to get to the last opened file.  So far I've tried `:1000n` to intentionally overshoot but that gives the error

> E165: Cannot go beyond last file

From there I just resort to a binary search trying to get to the end, which takes a while, i.e., `:500n`, `:250n`, `125n`, ...

**How can I get to the last opened file in vim?**

Comment: `:last` is correct but if you want to know how many files were on the command line, you can use `Ctrl-G` in command mode

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`:last`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Alast).

See `:help :last` for more details. You might be interested in the other commands around it for managing files in `:args` as well.